# Compare Date from TableB to several date ranges in TableA: Building WHERE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, between

I want to select items from TableB that have Start Date between one of the date ranges in VacationHistory (TableA) table.

Lets say I have VacationHistory datatable (TableA) that has Start and End date values. What I need to do is to compare a date from another datatable (TableB) to be between date ranges in VacationHistory (TableA). So if there are three entries in VacationHistory datatable, I would do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableB WHERE (
        (DateInTableB BETWEEN '2014-10-21' AND '2014-10-27')
     OR (DateInTableB BETWEEN '2014-11-05' AND '2014-11-13')
     OR (...)
)
```

However, how can I build this query using all date ranges in VacationHistory table in this WHERE clause. I guess there is nothing that I could say `BETWEEN IN (....)`.

Something that I tried, is to build a string of entire where clause::

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr + ' OR ' , '') + 
    ('DateInTableB BETWEEN ''' + CAST(StartDate AS NVARCHAR) + ''' AND ' 
              + '''' + CAST(EndDate AS NVARCHAR) + '''') 
FROM VacationHistory
SELECT @listStr
```

With `@listStr` having something like this: `DateInTableB BETWEEN '2014-11-05' AND '2014-11-13' OR DateInTableB BETWEEN '2014-10-21' AND '2014-10-27'`

However, I don't think I can use @listStr in where clause directly, like this:

```
WHERE (@listStr)
```

What could I do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to find the rows in TableB that have a Start Date in any of the date ranges in TableA you can use a correlated`exists`:

```
select * 
from TableB b 
where exists (
    select 1 
    from TableA a
    where b.StartDate between a.StartDate and a.EndDate
)
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/be3e4/1)

Answer (score 0):

A Simple `INNER JOIN` is what you need.

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.id,
       b.StartDate
FROM   TableB b
       JOIN TableA a
         ON b.StartDate BETWEEN a.StartDate AND a.EndDate
```

Or

```
SELECT *
FROM   TableB
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Min(StartDate) StartDate,
                          Max(EndDate)   EndDate
                   FROM   TableA) A
               ON DateInTableB BETWEEN A.StartDate AND A.EndDate
```

Still if you want the answer in the way you have tried then you need to have `Dynamic SQL`

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr + ' OR ' , '') + 
    ('DateInTableB BETWEEN ''' + CAST(StartDate AS NVARCHAR) + ''' AND ' 
              + '''' + CAST(EndDate AS NVARCHAR) + '''') 
FROM VacationHistory


set @sql = 'SELECT *
FROM TableB where '+@listStr+''

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Note that the query using an inner join would return the same id from TableB if if matches more than one date range in TableA unless you add a distinct or a group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM TableB
inner join 
(
select Min(StartDate) StartDate, Max(EndDate) EndDate From TableA
) A
on  DateInTableB between A.StartDate and A.EndDate
```